# ImageView Invisible/Visible

Tags: android, imageview, visibility

I have this imageView that I want to be Invisible at first... 
Then when I click a button (calculateButton),  the imageView will be Visible.

Here's my ImageView:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resultLabel"
     android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel"
     android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

And here's my code for the calculateButton:

```
     public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

    EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightText);
    EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
    TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);


    int weight = (int) Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
    int height = (int) Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
            int bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);



 String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

 resultText.setText("Your BMI is:" + " " + bmiValue  + " " +  bmiInterpretation); }

    }

  private int calculateBMI (int weight, int height) {

    return (int)  weight * 703 / (height * height) ;

        }
   private String interpretBMI(int bmiValue) {

            if (bmiValue <= 16.0 && bmiValue <= 18.5) {
                return "Underweight";   
            } else if (bmiValue > 18.5 && bmiValue <= 25 ){
                    return "Normal (Healthy)";
            } else if (bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue <= 30  ) {
                return "Overweight";
            } else {
                return "Obese"; }
            }

               }
```

Comment: then used `imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`  and `imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make image view invisible first and inside onclick make it visible.

So put this line in image-view of XML

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

so your full code look something like this.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resultLabel"
     android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel"
     android:visibility="invisible"
     android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

and then make it visible in button click event.

```
    imageview.setVisibility(View.visible);
```

Remember here `imageview` is your object on ImageView. so it looks like

```
 ImageView imageview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 imageview.setVisibility(View.visible);
```

So put it like this.

```
public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {


    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

    EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightText);
    EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
    TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

ImageView imageview =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
         imageview.setVisibility(View.visible);

         .......
         .......


if (bmiValue <= 16.0 && bmiValue <= 18.5){

imageview1.setVisibility(View.visible);
imageview2.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview3.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview4.setVisibility(View.invisible);

}else if (your second condition){
imageview1.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview2.setVisibility(View.visible);
imageview3.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview4.setVisibility(View.invisible);

}else if (your third condition){
imageview1.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview2.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview3.setVisibility(View.visible);
imageview4.setVisibility(View.invisible);

}else
{
imageview1.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview2.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview3.setVisibility(View.invisible);
imageview4.setVisibility(View.visible);
}
```

Here just replace your image-view with your ID and try. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yay! It worked! Thank you so much! And to the others that also helped... Thank you Thank you...

Comment: If it helped then Please accept the answer by clicking right below my answer. Check this, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yeah, great. @Deloy, Happy coding.

Comment: Hey Innocent, is it possible that I can still make other imageView pop up? For example, if (bmiValue <= 16.0 && bmiValue <= 18.5) , another imageView will pop Up..

Comment: I didn't get your question clearly. can you bit specify more exactly you are asking.

Comment: Oh sorry.. I mean if I have 4 imageView, and they are invisible... When I click the calculateButton, not all the 4 imageView will appear.. It depends on the result.. So if ever the result is 16.0, only the 1st imageView will appear.. Then the 3 imageView is still invisible..

Comment: where should i put those conditions? I'm confused where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set visibility

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Then on button click

```
public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

 ImageView iv =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

Avoid initializing imageview every time on button click

```
ImageView iv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager);
    iv =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnCreate()` set imageview **INVISIBLE** like `imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

and button `onClick()` **VISIBLE** it like `imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

try it out

visibility of imageview is invisible ......

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/resultLabel"
 android:layout_below="@+id/resultLabel"
 android:src="@drawable/image"
 android:visibility="invisible" />
```

and in your code..,at buton click put this line

```
imageview.setVisibility(View.visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably define the image as invisible in your layout XML... `android:visibility="invisible"`

You can modify the visibility of a view with `view.setVisibility(x);`, where x is `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.VISIBLE`, or `View.GONE`.
write this code in `onCreate()` method.

```
Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly set visibilty in xml gone

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

now from java code set visibility visible on onclick..

```
 imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```